# Download every file from a server directory using Renci.SshNet

Tags: c#, winforms, openssh

I've been working on this for a few days now and can't seem to figure out why I'm not able to download each and every file in the directory from my server. I am successfully able to download the very first file then after I get an access denied error.

Below is the code I use to connect to the server and start the download process.

```
    public void downloadPaperwork()
    {
        // Setup Credentials and Server Information
        ConnectionInfo ConnNfo = new ConnectionInfo(ipAddress, port, serverName,
            new AuthenticationMethod[]{
            // Key Based Authentication (using keys in OpenSSH Format)
            new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(serverName,new PrivateKeyFile[]{
                new PrivateKeyFile(keyFile,password)
            }),
            });

        using (var sftp = new SftpClient(ConnNfo))
        {
            sftp.Connect();

            sftp.ChangeDirectory("/var/www/html/invoices");

            List<SftpFile> invoices = sftp.ListDirectory(".").ToList();

            foreach (var file in invoices)
            {
                string filename = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath + folder, file.Name);

                using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    if(!file.Name.Equals(".") && !file.Name.Equals(".."))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(file.Name);
                        sftp.DownloadFile(file.FullName, fs);
                        fs.Close();
                    }

                }
            }
            sftp.Disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Below is the entire exception I recive during runtime:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\*****\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\********\**********\bin\Debug\****\Invoices' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
   at *********.Form1.downloadPaperwork() in C:\Users\******\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\*********\*********\Secretary Form.cs:line 173
   at ********.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\*****\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\*******\*******\Secretary Form.cs:line 120
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I've tried adding a file to the filestream and I don't get a error but it keeps replacing the one file only leaving me with the last file in the directory.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `C:\Users\*****\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\********\**********\bin\Debug\****\Invoices` is where the error is and it looks like its a folder and not a file. You need to modify your code to skip folders (or traverse folders).

Comment: use the debugger.. I are you sure that the connect is still open when you get to the 2nd iteration? try checking the sftp connection state. also where is invoices declared in this line `foreach (var file in invoices)`

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Edited my question forgot to add that part

Comment: What I would do is just wrap your code thats inside your `foreach` block inside a `try` block and `catch` the `UnauthorizedAccessException` exception and just `continue` the loop inside that.

Comment: since you issues a `Change Directory` wouldn't you think that this line `List<SftpFile> invoices = sftp.ListDirectory(".").ToList();` you should replace the `.` with `sftp.ListDirectory(sftp.WorkingDirectory)` ..?

Comment: @Icemanind the try catch worked like a charm. If you post a answer Ill be glad to give you the credit...

Comment: @MethodMan I've did both and both gave the same result.

Comment: Receiving directory probably does not exist.  Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, folder));

Comment: Also change this line  Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath + folder, file.Name); to Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, folder, file.Name);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you are fetching directories in addition to files. I would just wrap your code in a `try` block and `catch` the `UnauthorizedAccessException` exception and place a `continue` inside your `catch` block.